# CSS and Html resize login form height without squashing the textbox on smaller screen?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a login form that when viewed on smaller screens the textboxes becomes squashed down to a very narrow height.  When I set the height for the parent `login-form` and `login-container` containers the height of the parent increases but not the textboxes, they remain narrow. 
Q: How can I make the height more when viewed on a small screen?
Html:

```
    <!-- Login form -->
    <div  class="login-form animate" >
        <form action= "" method="post">
            <div class="login-container ">
                <h2>Welcome!</h2>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Username.." name="uname" id="uname" required>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password.." name="passw" id="passw" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value= <?php echo $_SESSION["loggedin"] ?> >

                <button class="logbut" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</button>

            </div>
        </form>
        <form action= "index.php" method="post">
            <div class="login-container ">
                <label>
                    <input class="pswreset" type="submit" name="forgot" id="forgot" value="Forgot password?">
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.login-container {
    padding: 16px;
}

.login-form {
    left: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    width:25%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/*Small media devices specific styles*/
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
/*-------------Login page------------*/
    .login-form, .login-topnav {
        width: 100%;
        max-width:100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;

    }

    .login-container {
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width:100%;
        padding: 0px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my question.  You just set the individual textboxes to a desired height unit, in my case `6vh     Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*` i.e.:

```
/*Small media devices specific styles*/
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
/*-------------Login page------------*/
    input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {
        width: 99%;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 6vh;
    }
```